# Rewriting rules in will send me to different page than requested

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following rewriting rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Category\.php\?Category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /C/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^C/([^/]+)/?$ Category.php?Category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

the redirect work fine if you work from the home page, however when click trough to a product page on the /C/Category Name page it cannot find the product page. It is searching like so

```
http://localhost/C/product.php?id=302-Product-name
```

I presume that is because it thinks you are in a different folder.
Not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add the `<base href="/" />` so it will send all the links back to the root.
Thanks so much again @anubhava from previous questions

Comment: Yes that is helpful. You can accept your answer whenever SO lets you do that.

Comment: @anubhava wondering if you can help me with another question, I know its has been a long time however you seem to have help somebody a while ago with a similar question. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988992/redirect-a-domain-from-https-to-http?noredirect=1#comment78938227_45988992