# Redirect a domain from HTTPs to HTTP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I have on my server 3 different domains, on the main domain I have an SSL certificate, on the other 2 I have not.

So the main site is displaying

However the other two are displayed as

and

as these domains have no SSL certificate it gives and error in IE/FIREFOX/CHROME
however it seems fine in safari

I have tried to force the two domains to display http however un succesfull

This is in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

As i understand this redirects all the domains to https
I tried the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.examplemydomain.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L,NE]
```

However unsuccessful, any help is welcome.

Comment: Probably you will get your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess

Comment: @Just_Do_It That is when you only have one domain, I have 3 domains and I want 2 of them redirected back to http. Thanks for looking anyway

Comment: @anubhava thanks so much for looking. I tried for the domain1 with the rules above in place however that didn't work

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get for `http://domain2.com` request.

Comment: Also show your complete .htaccess in question.

Comment: I am not getting any thing in  the networking tab as the site want to show up as https not as http. Sorry if Im doing it wrong

Comment: the other redirects that are in there are the once for the main domain they are for example: Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase /

rewritecond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Category_Recent\.php\?pageNum_RS_Search=([^\s&]+)&totalRows_RS_Search=([^\s&]+)&Category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$

Comment: Not in comment, edit your question and provide rules there.